# Visual studio 2019 exit with "Docker command failed with exit code -1073741515"

Tags: visual-studio, docker

When running my .net core web API project using Docker in visual studio 2019, I am having the below error message. Any idea why?
However, when running the app using IIS Express, everything seems to be running fine. Thank you

```
1>C:\Users\XXXXXX\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.10.8\build\Container.targets(138,5): warning CTP1006: Failed to stop the application within the container. Build may fail because the files are in use.
1>C:\Users\XXXXXX\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.10.8\build\Container.targets(138,5): warning CTP1006: Docker command failed with exit code -1073741515.
```

Comment: How'd this turn out? Any luck?